# inverse laplace transform of $\frac{s^3}{(s^2+4)^2}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, derivatives, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

Using partial fractions gives $\frac{s}{s^2+4}$ - $\frac{4s}{(s^2+4)^2}$

Inverse laplace transform of the first member ($\frac{s}{s^2+4}$) is cos(2t). 
Can't figure out how to transform $\frac{4s}{(s^2+4)^2}$
. Help needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that
\begin{align}
\frac{s^3}{(s^2+4)^2}&=\frac{s(s^2+4)-4s}{(s^2+4)^2}=\frac{s}{s^2+4}-\frac{4s}{(s^2+4)^2}
\end{align}

Also notice $\mathscr{L}\left\{\sin (2t)\right\}=\frac{2}{s^2+4}\,\,$ and $\,\,\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}\left(\frac{2}{s^2+4}\right)=-\frac{4s}{s^2+4}$. Then use the fact that
$$\mathscr{L}\left\{tf(t)\right\}=-\frac{\mathrm dF(s)}{\mathrm d s}$$
where $F(s)=\mathscr{L}\left\{f(t)\right\}$.

Comment: yeah, my bad. forgot to add that 4 in here, but i wrote it on paper haha.

Comment: well yeah, thats one way to do it, but that could take too much time while you're trying to logically find out how did that transformation happen. is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @user3104311:     
Yes, you can use the Convolution theorem.